# javascript - make JSON attributes keys links on the first level

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need to prettify some JSON to display within an HTML `<pre>` section.

The working javascript code I use is..

```
function transformJson(k, v) {

  if (k === 'href' && typeof v === 'string') {
      var label = v.replace(/&/gi, '&amp;');
    return '<a href=' + v + '>' + label + '</a>';
  }
  return v;
}

function jsonFormat(jsonString) {

   var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString, transformJson);
   return JSON.stringify(jsonObj, undefined, 2)
            .replace(/\s"(\w*)":/g, ' "<span class="key">$1</span>":')
            .replace(/:\s"(.*)"/g, ': "<span class="string">$1</span>"');
};
```

Now I would like to make all attributes keys at the first level, regardless of the attribute value, links to *"/documentation#attributeKeyText"*.

```
var jsonToPrettify = {
  "href": "link/me",
  "nonHrefButMakeThisKeyALink": "some_text",
  "obj": {
    "href": "link/me",
    "thisKeyWontBeALinkInsteadBecauseHasAParent": "some_text"
  }
}

console.log( jsonFormat( JSON.stringify( jsonToPrettify ) ) );
```

How can I achieve that?
How can I check that the current attribute has no parent object?

Thanks

**UPDATE**:

Output of the current version is:

```
{
  "<span class="key">href</span>": "<span class="string"><a href=link/me>link/me</a></span>",
  "<span class="key">nonHrefButMakeThisKeyALink</span>": "<span class="string">some_text</span>",
  "<span class="key">obj</span>": {
    "<span class="key">href</span>": "<span class="string"><a href=link/me>link/me</a></span>",
    "<span class="key">thisKeyWontBeALinkInsteadBecauseHasAParent</span>": "<span class="string">some_text</span>"
  }
}
```

So I just want the span *nonHrefButMakeThisKeyALink* to be a link instead..

Comment: What's the point of stringifying the object to JSON and then parse it and then stringify it again?

Comment: I receive the json in string form from another service. That console.log is just to allow to copy the whole question in the console and see it in action..

Comment: This could help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518762/change-key-name-in-nested-json-structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adding this after JSON.parse did the trick..

```
var newObj = {};

for(var attr in jsonObj){
    if( jsonObj[attr].constructor != Object && attr != 'href'){
        newObj['<a href="/documentation#'+attr+'">'+attr+'</a>'] = jsonObj[attr];
    }else{
        newObj[attr] = jsonObj[attr];
    }
}
```

(And then clearly JSON.stringify applied to *newObj*)

Answer (score 1):

Topmost object is passed to function provided as [parameter for JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) under empty key.
You need to include that in your `transformJson`:

```
function transformJson(k, v) {
  if (k === 'href' && typeof v === 'string') {
    var label = v.replace(/&/gi, '&amp;');
    return '<a href=' + v + '>' + label + '</a>';
  } else if (k === '') {
    for (var x in v) {
      //skipping 'href' because it's handled by previous 'if'
      if (x !== 'href' && typeof v[x] === 'string') {
        var label = v[x].replace(/&/gi, '&amp;');
        v[x] = '<a href=/documentation#' +  x  + '>' + label + '</a>';
      }
    }
  }
  return v;
}
```